# EOF when reading a line or idk

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am just doing a program that does the following thing.

1. You input "count" of something.
2. Then you input a value for every "count" separated by spaces
3. You get the output: How many of them are duplicated and which duplicated number is the highest again separated by space

basically this : 
Input:

```
8           
12 12 16 102 47 16 102 47
```

Output:

```
4 102
```

The problem is that didn't get a single point for my code and I have no idea where the problem is.
In works in my python but it does not in some online compilers so the reciever may have the same problem with my program as the online sites

```
def thing():
    global count
    count = int(input('n:'))
    if count > 100000:
        exit()
    elif count < 1:
        exit()
    else:
        wut()
def wut():
    idk = []
    inp = list(map(int,input('ai:').split(' ')))
    if len(inp) != count:
        exit()
    elif sum(inp) > 200000:
        exit()
    elif sum(inp) < 1:
        exit()
    else:
        for i in range(len(inp)):
            for x in range(i+1, len(inp)): 
                if inp[i] == inp[x]:
                    idk.append(inp[i])
    o = len(idk)
    idk.sort(reverse = True)
    print(o, idk[0])

thing()
```

In my python 3.7.4 it works just fine but I didn't get a single point for this.

Comment: What do you mean by 'single point'?

Comment: What does "idk" mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

# Convert them all to an int
numbers = [int(i) for i in input("Numbers: ").split(" ")]

# Get number of input
count = len(numbers)

counter = Counter(numbers)

# Get the highest value of the most common values
max_dup, _ = max(counter.most_common(), key=lambda ele: ele[0])

# Get the amount of duplicates
dups = len(list(filter(lambda k: k[1] > 1, counter.items())))

print(dups, end=" ")

print(max_dup)
```

[collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)
[filter](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/filter)